# Opening MDF4 (.mf4) file using python

Tags: python, mdf

I am trying to read `.mf4` file using python 3.7 (Spyder IDE). The main idea of reading `.mf4` file is to see if I can access each information separately.
That means, for example, to check the Road Signs detection points only or Pedestrian identifications only or to extract video only.. and at the later stage to count the FP/FN/TP/TN and link it to the frame counter using GPS data.

I tried to use `asammdf` library.

Following is the function i used:

```py
from asammdf import MDF, Signal
data = MDF('filename.mf4')
```

I get the error as follows :

> bus_type = channel_group.acq_source.bus_type
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bus_type'

Answer (score 2):

I've pushed a fix to the development branch.

You can install the code by running:

```
pip install -I --no-deps https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/archive/development.zip
```

If you have other problems please open a new issue on github

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But its unfortunately not getting installed.ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /danielhrisca/asammdf/archive/development.zip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BB973DD8D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Comment: if you have a network proxy then you need to provide it in the command line ``pip pip install -I --no-deps --proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<server_address>:<server_port> https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/archive/development.zip`` by replacing the user, password, server_address and server_port with your settings

Comment: I would really love to switch to asammdf lib if it has a solution for this challenge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287301/how-to-read-dat-file-from-aws-s3-using-mdfreader ? Can you help with this? @danielhrisca

Comment: @AakashBasu maybe this can help you https://github.com/CSS-Electronics/api-examples/blob/master/examples/other/s3-basics/s3_basics.py

Comment: I know those operations, trying to figure out a way to read MDF in such a bytestream format and parse. Can you check my query in the link above pls?

Comment: The MDF spec allows for really fragmented files, so streaming is not a viable option. You would be doing a lot of random access over the network

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
from asammdf import MDF, Signal

mdf= MDF(version ="4.10")

path=mdf("file path")
```

Comment: Error `TypeError: 'MDF' object is not callable`

Comment: Also when importing `ldf is not supported
xls is not supported
xlsx is not supported`